# How to integrate Shiprocket API in e-commerce application to create a custom order in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest

I am integrating Shiprocket API in my e-commerce application it is working fine when I post a simple request, but when I POST a request with a Json list, it is showing an error:

> Remote Server return an error 422  Unprocessable Entity

My code:

```
string postData = data;
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

this.Status = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

Comment: It's rather dependent on the server receiving the request you're making (422 is a server response), and the contents of your request. For example, if `postData` isn't form-encoded data, the server might be rejecting it. Unfortunately you haven't provided any information with which we can actually determine if this might be the case so all we can do is speculate.

Answer (score 0):

I am using HttpClient instead of HttpWebRequest

```
static async Task<string> PostURI(Uri u, HttpContent c)
    {
        string tokenId = "XXXXX";

        var response = string.Empty;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
                     = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tokenId);

            HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync(u, c);
           // HttpResponseMessage response1 = client.PostAsync(u).Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {                   
                response = result.StatusCode.ToString();                    

            }
        }          

       // Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
       // Console.ReadLine();

        return response;
    }
```

and Call this Method inside this

```
public void hitApi()
    {
        List<itemList> itmlst = new List<itemList>();
        itemList itm = new itemList();
        itm.name = "Apple I7";
        itm.sku = "AS0125";
        itm.units = 1;
        itm.selling_price = 25000;
        itm.discount = 0;
        itm.tax = 0;
        itm.hsn = 04520;
        itmlst.Add(itm);
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(itmlst);
        int subt = 900;
        int length = 10;
        int breadth = 15;
        int height = 10;
        int weight = 5;

        string postData = "{\"order_id\":\"23323535\",\"order_date\":\"2019-11-22 11:11\",\"pickup_location\":\"Home\",\"billing_customer_name\":\"Vinay Kumar yadav\",\"billing_last_name\":\"Hassan\",\"billing_address\":\"House 221B, New Madeygunj  Village\",\"billing_city\":\"Lucknow\",\"billing_pincode\":\"226020\",\"billing_state\":\"Uttar Pradesh\",\"billing_country\":\"India\",\"billing_email\":\"jaanu.2010@gmail.com\",\"billing_phone\":\"7545201020\",\"shipping_is_billing\":true,\"order_items\":" + json + ",\"payment_method\":\"Prepaid\",\"sub_total\":" + subt + ",\"length\":" + length + ",\"breadth\":" + breadth + ",\"height\":" + height + ",\"weight\":" + weight + "}";


        Uri u = new Uri("https://apiv2.shiprocket.in/v1/external/orders/create/adhoc");
        var payload = postData;

        HttpContent c = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var t = Task.Run(() => PostURI(u, c));
        t.Wait();

        Response.Write(t.Result);
    }
```

Comment: Is this the solution? If so, it seems likely that it isn't anything to do with using HttpClient vs HttpWebRequest, but rather that in your question you were declaring the content as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but here you're declaring it as `application/json`. If you originally sent JSON but declared `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then I'm not surprised the server didn't understand it. In plain text the form encoded looks like `order_id=23323535&order_date=2019-11-22%2011%3A11&pickup_location=home&billing_customer_name=Vinay%20Kumar%20yadav`, etc.

Comment: I have tried both 'application/json and 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' but error remains same, but this resolved my Problem.